# C++ Unix Socket capturing system calls

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pipe

I am attempting to monitor a long running daemon using a monitoring application which creates a UNIX socket and listens.  In testing, however, I have found that calls I am making to the system on other threads within the application are showing up in this socket.

```
// Output from Server Test Application (just echoing from recv buffer)
# serverTest /tmp/receiver-programmer-socket
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.51 (192.168.1.51): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.51 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.52 (192.168.1.52): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.52 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.51 (192.168.1.51): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.51 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.52 (192.168.1.52): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.52 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
```

The long running daemon is already created and outputs to a socket if available.  At the moment it is just writting "test" to the socket every second.

```
// Long Running Daemon Snippet
int Monitor::write_to_socket(){
    std::string string = "test";
    char buffer[1024];
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(buffer, string.c_str());
    if (send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0)
    {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Error sending to socket");
        close(sockfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have pasted together a quick server application to test that everything was working correctly, so the code is very rough.

```
/* a server in the unix domain.  The pathname of
   the socket address is passed as an argument */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void error(const char *);
int connection_handler(int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // File descriptors
    int sockfd, newsockfd;

    // Length of address string
    int servlen;

    //
    int n;

    // Size of client address
    socklen_t clilen;

    // Client socket address
    struct sockaddr_un  cli_addr;

    // Server socket address
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;

    // Character buffer
    char buf[80];

    // Create socket
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        error("creating socket");

    // Sets server address area to all zeros   
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    // Sets server address family to local interprocess
    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

    // Sets server address path to passed in argument
    strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, argv[1]);

    // Sets length of full server address
    servlen = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);

    // Bind socket at address and port (sortof)
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, servlen) < 0)
        error("binding socket");

    // Start listening for requests
    listen(sockfd, 5);

    pid_t child;
    int connection_fd;
    socklen_t address_length;
    while((connection_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &address_length)) > -1)
    {
        child = fork();
        if(child == 0)
        {
            /* now inside newly created connection handling process */
            return connection_handler(connection_fd);
        }

        /* still inside server process */
        close(connection_fd);
    }
    return 0;
}

int connection_handler(int connection_fd)
{
 int nbytes;
 char buffer[256];

 while(1) {
    bzero((char *)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    // Corrected to test for correct return and buffer size
    if((nbytes = recv(connection_fd, buffer, 256, 0)) > 0)
    {    
       buffer[nbytes] = 0;
       printf("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);
    }
 }

 close(connection_fd);
 return 0;
}

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}
```

I'm not certain how the calls are being introduced to the socket.  There are no sockets used anywhere else in this application.  Is there a buffer that I should be clearing before writting or reading from the socket?

Portion from `strace` output.

```
[pid 15286] close(4)                    = 0
[pid 15286] accept(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 15296] recv(4, "test", 256, 0)     = 4
[pid 15296] fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
[pid 15296] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40001000
[pid 15296] write(1, "MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test\n", 26MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: test
) = 26
[pid 15296] recv(4, "PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50)"..., 256, 0) = 103
[pid 15296] write(1, "MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.16"..., 124MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.156 ms
) = 124
[pid 15296] write(1, "\n", 1
)           = 1
[pid 15296] recv(4, "\n--- 192.168.1.50 ping statistic"..., 256, 0) = 142
[pid 15296] write(1, "MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: \n--- 192.16"..., 163MESSAGE FROM CLIENT:
--- 192.168.1.50 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.156/2.156/2.156 ms
) = 163
[pid 15296] write(1, "\n", 1
)           = 1
[pid 15296] recv(4, "PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50)"..., 256, 0) = 103
[pid 15296] write(1, "MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.16"..., 124MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.063 ms
) = 124
```

It appears to be like the message is being read in correctly.  I will work on parsing the output from the daemon's strace to see if it uncovers anything.

**UPDATE**
I was not able to determine the source of this issue.  I rewrote all system calls to output to `/dev/null` and still received the warning and error messages in the socket.  I attempted to switch to a TCP socket but encountered the same issue.  `strace` didn't reveal any send or write calls on the socket that would lead to these calls appearing.

Eventual solution was to use telnet and ANSI controls to constantly rewrite telnet output to mask warning messages.

Comment: Use `strace` to undestand which syscalls are done by your app. Perhaps you need to multiplex with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: I doubt this is coming from the monitoring thread. They're just both printing to stdout, so their output is mixed together on your screen.

Comment: You're not checking for an error from `recv`. If it returns `-1`, `buffer[nbytes] = 0;` will cause you to write outside the buffer.

Comment: @Barmar, I've modified the code in question to check for errors and buffer size, but I am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: `sockfd` is a global variable in the daemon? I suspect some other part of your code has a bug that's causing it to write to that FD.

Comment: `sockfd` is a private variable of the `Monitor` class.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I had to find strace that would work on ARM, but I found one compiled it and added the response to the original question.

Comment: buffer[nbytes] = 0; try making that buffer[nbytes] = '\0';

Comment: @Alex, the `strace` shows that it's not a buffer issue.  The socket is actually being read from correctly, there is just misc data being written to the socket from somewhere.

Comment: This is most likely an errant `close` call. For example, the one in `Monitor::write_to_socket` seems errant, since you close the socket but don't do anything else different from when you don't close the socket -- so other code has no idea the socket no longer refers to what it used to refer to. If you call this function more than once, things go horribly wrong if the first call closes the socket and an in-between function opens a file.

Comment: I probably should have included more code at the time of this question, and I don't have the code any longer, but the call isn't errant.  If it was successfully sent, it returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and the calling function knows that the socket is still good.  If it fails, then the socket is closed and `EXIT_FAILURE` is returned, and the code rebuilds the socket.

Comment: This question should probably be closed at this point.  I have no way to testing any solution which is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the buffer and the chance is minimal that some other part  of the program is writing to your buffer, since the buffer is allocated on stack. It seems that the message is received on the socket, but is strange for a normal Linux that the socket fd=3, you don't have any open files?

For example:

```
nbytes = recv(connection_fd, buffer, 256, 0)
buffer[nbytes] = \0;
```

When nbytes is 256 you are writing outside the buffer, which can cause even segmentation faults.

```
connection_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &address_length)
```

Overwriting server address, it should be cli_addr probably

Comment: I appreciate the help, and good catch on the `nbytes` bug, but the error isn't actually in the output on screen.  The actual socket is receiving the messages that were being sent to `stdout` by ping on the sending device.  The device that the listening portion is running on is entirely separate from the sending device, so the `ping` output is coming from the socket.  The baffling part is that the `write_to_socket` function is closed, and uses a static value `test`, so there is no way that the `ping` output is being accidentally passed to this function.

Comment: What arguments are you using to start server?

Comment: I don't believe I passed in any arguments.  Unfortunately the code is all gone now, and I have no way of recovering it.  In the end, I ended up masking the problem, and eventually changed hardware which resolved the problem, so I am fairly positive it might have had something to do with the version of `ping` that was compiled for that hardware (older ARM build).